# How to create ActiveXObject in javascript function which is called using Silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight, activexobject

I am trying to call javascript function from my Silverlight C# file. (Able to call it).
Then i try to create ActiveXObject object in order to launch notepad in javascript function.
But Automation server does not allow to create ActiveXObject object.

How to create ActiveXObject object without enabling Out-of-Browser settings of Silverlight Web Project?

Any other way to create COM object in Silvleright without enabling OOB settings will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: no.  By design and for very good reasons in-browser code (be that inside Silverlight Application) and in Javascript you can't arbitarily launch any automation server.  Could you imagine the havoc that would be wrought if just visiting a website could cause the launch and manipulation of all sort of apps on your computer?